# Can I access the Error Log in arcpy?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcpy

Can the error log created by validate topology be assessed through arcpy? I can validate the following topology -

```
arcpy.ValidateTopology_management(r"C:\WorkSpace\CWD.gdb\FD\FD_Topology")
```

Can I access the log created without entering ArcMap? I don't need to be able to fix errors. I just want to know that there are not errors before exporting features. If they exist and I can verify that, I can raise an exception.

Answer (score 6):

ArcToolbox history is saved (on Win7 at least) at:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcToolbox\History
```

There are also XML logs at:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcToolbox\log
```

These might help you out.

Comment: Use `os.path.expandvars(r'%APPDATA%\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcToolbox\History')`, etc.